# Building a two-dimensional list from a one-dimensional list using Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a one-dimensional list that looks somewhat like this:

```
["Break 1", "1234", "3212", "9393", "7417", "Break 2", "9212", "2911", ..., ]
```

... and what I need is to convert it to this:

```
[["1234", "3212", "9393", "7417"], ["9212", "2911", ...,]]
```

I.e, the constant size 1d list contains strings of numbers separated by the item "Break X" where X is some number/id of the "group". The numbers following the "Break X" marker should be considered the contents of the group, and the groups are array items in the final 2d list.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give more details? For instance, is the length of the list constant? Do you need only the first four elements in the first list or half of the elements of the original list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are sure that your input list always adheres to the structure that you described (begins with a delimiter "Break X" element, "Break X" elements are numbered consecutively), simple recursion and list arithmetics should be enough:

```
% process_list(List1,List2):
% List2 is the list of sublists of List1 when split up according to
% delimiter elements as defined by is_delimiter/1. First element of
% List1 has to be a delimiter.
process_list([],[]).
process_list([Element|Rest],[List|Lists]) :-
        is_delimiter(Element),
        process_sublist(Rest,List,NewRest),
        process_list(NewRest,Lists).

% process_sublist(+List1,-List2,-List3):
% Splits List1 up into List2 and List3, where List2 is everything
% until the first delimiter element.
process_sublist([Element|Rest],[Element|List],NewRest) :-
        \+ is_delimiter(Element), !,
        process_sublist(Rest,List,NewRest).
process_sublist(List,[],List).

% delimiter = string of the form "Break X"
is_delimiter(String) :-
        sub_string(String,0,_,_,"Break ").
```

Example output:

```
?- process_list(["Break 1", "1234", "3212", "9393", "7417", "Break 2", "9212", "2911"],X).
X = [["1234", "3212", "9393", "7417"], ["9212", "2911"]].

?- process_list(["Break 1", "1234", "3212", "9393", "7417", "Break 2", "9212", "2911", "Break 3", "8357", "837", "67865"],X).
X = [["1234", "3212", "9393", "7417"], ["9212", "2911"], ["8357", "837", "67865"]].

?- process_list(["Break 1", "1234", "3212", "9393", "7417", "Break 2", "9212", "2911", "Break 3", "8357", "837", "67865", "Break 4", "Break 5"],X).
X = [["1234", "3212", "9393", "7417"], ["9212", "2911"], ["8357", "837", "67865"], [], []].
```